# Generating a Table Using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a list of outcomes and the number of times each outcome occurred. I want to generate a table of outcomes on a second sheet where the number of rows for each outcome is the number of times it occurred. Here's what I have so far:

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
    a = B3
    b = C3

Sheets("Sheet2").Activate
    Range("B" & "2" & ":B" & "b").Select
    ActiveCell = "a"
```

a is the outcome and b is the number of times it happened

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code had two flaws:

- it uses “b” (which is the string “b”) instead of the variable b
- it misses one row (b should be b + 1)

So it becomes:

```
Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B2:" & (b + 1)).Value = a
```

Comment: @JakeKruk, you are welcome. You may then consider marking the answer as accepted. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try reshaping the target with Resize.

```
dim a as variant, b as long

with workSheets("Sheet1")
    a = .range("B3").value
    b = .range("C3").value
end with

with workSheets("Sheet2")
    .Range("B2").resize(b, 1) = a
end with
```